# Pairing digits from a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to write a Python program that gets a number from the keyboard, and outputs a number built from the minimum of each pair of digits of the original number. For example:

```
Enter number please:  84372216
Original number: 84372216 
New number:   4321
```

I had an idea to transform the original number into a string, to create a list of digits (chars) in the odd locations and the even locations, and then to compare them by the index of the lists. This doesn't sound too efficient or easy to implement, as it involves too many conversions from int to string and vice versa. The advantage is that this solves easily the problem of a number with odd number of digits.

Is there a way of solving this problem without using strings ?

Thank you.

Comment: No conversions needed: `s = input(); ''.join([min(t) for t in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])])`. For numbers with odd number of digits you could use `zip_longest`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think the primary concern of OP for not using string is that he think it would require a lot of conversions from string to int, which is clearly not the case. I didn't get your second part of comment.

Comment: @RoryDaulton After `s = input()` `s` is a string. I only used empty string in `''.join`, what should I have used instead? I don't get the last sentence either.

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip()` on slices of the original number and `min()` on each `tuple` returned:

```
>>> number = input('Enter number please: ')
Enter number please: 84372216
>>> print('Original number: {}'.format(number))
Original number: 84372216
>>> new_number = ''.join(min(tup) for tup in zip(number[::2], number[1::2]))
>>> print('New number: {}'.format(new_number))
New number: 4321
```

Answer (score 2):

```
num = 84372216
int(''.join(min(i) for i in zip(*[iter(str(num))]*2)))
#4321
```

`list(zip(*[iter(str(num))]*2))` splits num into pairs as below

```
[('8', '4'), ('3', '7'), ('2', '2'), ('1', '6')]
```

Then use `min` and `join` combination to get the output

Answer (score 2):

Transhuman's answer is cool, but here's a more readable version:

```
s = str(num)
r = int(''.join(min(s[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)))
```

Another nifty trick is to use `re.findall`:

```
r = int(''.join(min(i) for i in re.findall('..', str(num))))
```

**EDIT**

I didn't notice you said "without using strings". In that case:

```
def f(n):
    return n if n < 10 else min(n % 10, n // 10 % 10) + 10 * f(n // 100)
```

Comment: Is this code not working or am I missing something ? It gave me 8321 for the above example. I mean the second code, without strings. The string code works nice.

Comment: Nope, it's working. You sure you haven't called it on ``8437221`` or ``8437216`` by mistake (note that it works left to right)?

Answer (score 1):

It's quick and dirty, but it works:

```
def pairmin( n ):
        result = 0
        mult = 1
        while n > 0:
                if n > 10:
                        result =  min( n % 10, (n / 10) % 10 ) * mult + result
                else:
                        result = n * mult + result
                n = n / 100
                mult = mult * 10
        return result

print( pairmin( 84372216 ) )
print( pairmin( 8372216 ) )
```

Comment: It works on my machine! I wouldn't have posted it otherwise. The first call prints 4321 and the second one 8321.

Comment: I though that the second should start with 3, am I wrong ?

Comment: I thought it would be 8 as it is an odd number of digits?

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of what Vaultah posted in comment above. You can use `map` function, supply it with consecutive pairs and determine minimum from it.

```
 s = "84372216"
 "".join(list(map(lambda x,y: str(min([x,y])), s[::2],s[1::2])))
 #'4321'
```

Here `map(lambda x, y: str(min([x,y]))` takes two arguments from iterable `s[::2],s[1::2]` and determine what is the minimum value from the supplied args. Min result is being cast to `str` to join the final result. You can however cast the result back to `int` if you require further processing of result. Just add `int()` to overall expression.

To unserstand `s[::2],s[1::2]`, please check [Understand Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation). Slice notation works like `s[start:end:step]`